# How do you split seperate items in a list into tuples in python?

Tags: python, list, file, tuples

Okay so I have a file with names of some cars and how old they are in years, layed out like this but each one is a new line:

```
Ford Focus - 5
Ford Focus - 7
Ford Focus - 3
VW Golf - 2
VW Golf - 6
VW Golf - 1
```

I am trying to find a way to tuple this, but so the details are seperate tuples like this:

> [(Ford Focus - 5), (Ford Focus - 7), (Ford Focus - 3), (VW Golf - 2), (VW Golf - 6), (VW Golf - 1)]

Thanks

Comment: Is it a `csv` file or a `txt` file?

Comment: Do you want a one-element tuple? What you have written does even look like a tuple. One element tuple looks like: `(1,)` (has got a comma after the first element).

Comment: Welcome to SO! what have you tried so far ?

Comment: what's kind of tupple that is? why i can't see comma in the tupples?

Comment: @Andrey Please change your tuples to either `('Ford Focus', 5)` or `('Ford Focus - 5', )`

Answer (score 2):

I believe, what you really want is a list of tuples of form `(brand, year)`. If this is the case, then

```
def parse_car_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as car_file:
        return [line.rstrip().split(" - ") for line in car_file]
```

Otherwise

```
def parse_car_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as car_file:
        return [(line.rstrip(),) for line in car_file]
```

Comment: The first one is the best way if OP wants that

Comment: @jamylak I gave both examples in case OP really wants those one-element tuples for some reason beyond my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

## list comprehension

```
data = [(line.strip(),) for line in open('file', 'r')]
```

## for loop

```
data = []
for line in open('file', 'r') # for every line in file
    lst.append( (line.strip(),) ) # strip the line, make it to a tuple and append to lst
```